# C# OutOfMemory exception when returning a small DataTable

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have a SQLite database that has a single table with 18 million rows and 24 columns. I have written a SQL query function in C#, which I expose to Excel with ExcelDNA.

This is the complete code,

```
    string constr = constr = "Data Source=" + FilePath + ";Version=3;Synchronous=OFF;temp_store=memory;cache_size=700000;count_changes=off;";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {                                
        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(constr);
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(SQLStatement,conn);                
        conn.Open();                
        SQLiteDataAdapter sda = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);                                
        sda.Fill(dt);
        sda.Dispose();
        command.Dispose();
        conn.Dispose();
        int numRows = (IncludeHeaders ? dt.Rows.Count + 1 : dt.Rows.Count);
        object[,] ret = new object[numRows, dt.Columns.Count];
        int rowCount = 0;
        if (IncludeHeaders)
        {
            int colCount = 0;
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                ret[rowCount, colCount] = col.ColumnName;
                colCount++;
            }
        }
        rowCount = (IncludeHeaders ? 1 : 0);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            int colCount = 0;
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                if (row[col] != DBNull.Value)
                    ret[rowCount, colCount] = row[col];
                else
                    ret[rowCount, colCount] = "";
                colCount++;
            }
            rowCount++;
        }
        return ret;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        object[,] err = new object[1, 1];
        err[0, 0] = ex.ToString();
        return err;
    }
    finally
    {
        dt.Clear();
        dt.Dispose();
        dt = null;  
    }
```

If I run the query twice (two hits of Shift+F9), I get an OutOfMemoryException. In the Task Manager I can see the Working Set(Memory) of the EXCEL.EXE image go from 200MB to 1500MB before the exception is thrown.

However, this behavior isn't entirely consistent. Other queries where I return upto 5 columns and 1100 rows work just fine. I see the memory usage tick up in the Task Manager and once the results are returned to Excel I see the memory come back down.

Debugging the application above shows that it trips up at the `sda.Fill(dt)` line.

Would appreciate any thoughts? Would I be better off using `SQLiteDataReader` instead? Or are there any other tips or tricks I can use? Thank you.

Incidentally if I run the exact query via Python I don't get this problem, so I'd assume it's something to do with the garbage collection in C#.

Here are some details on the database and query. The schema is along the lines of,

```
Date (VARCHAR)
CompanyName (VARCHAR)
Amount (REAL)
AggCode (VARCHAR)
Level1 ... Level20 (VARCHAR)
```

The queries are usually run combining the fields `Level9`, `Level5`, `AggCode`, `Date`, `CompanyName` in the `WHERE` clause. So apart from the raw table, I have also configured the following four indices,

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 on my(Level09, AggCode);
CREATE INDEX idx2 on my(Level05, AggCode);
CREATE INDEX idx3 on my(CompanyName, AggCode);
CREATE INDEX idx4 on my(Date, AggCode);
```

The query that returns 1100 rows and 2 columns successfully,

```
SELECT CompanyName, SUM(Amount) FROM my where Level09="T_EU" and AggCode = "R_S_V" GROUP BY CompanyName ORDER BY SUM(Amount) DESC
```

The query that throws the memory exception,

```
SELECT Date, CompanyName, Sum(Amount) FROM my WHERE Level05 ="M_TO" AND AggCode = "C_DTA" GROUP BY Date, CompanyName
```

The second query returns 163 rows and 3 columns in Python.

The full stack trace of the exception is below,

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x80004005): out of memory
out of memory
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Reset(SQLiteStatement stmt)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Step(SQLiteStatement stmt)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
at UtilXL.Utils.UtilsSQLite.RunQueryCSLite(String SQLStatement, String FilePath, Boolean IncludeHeaders) in h:\Projects\UtilXL\UtilXL\Utils\UtilsSQLite.cs:line 37
```

Line 37 in referenced above is the `sda.Fill()` call.

If I use `SqlDataReader` then it falls over at the `ExecuteReader()` command,

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x80004005): out of memory
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Reset(SQLiteStatement stmt)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Step(SQLiteStatement stmt)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult() 
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader()
at UtilXL.Utils.UtilsSQLite.RunQueryCSReader(String SQLStatement, String FilePath, Boolean IncludeHeaders) in h:\Projects\UtilXL\UtilXL\Utils\UtilsSQLite.cs:line 111
```

Comment: Show that query

Comment: Could you show what your `SQLStatement` is? The `Fill`method should'n be causing any problem

Comment: 18 million records isn't small for Excel... 18 million * 24 = 432 million cells. Which means that your sheet will be 432MB if every cells contains 1 byte. The average is probably higher.

Comment: Hmm, I still don't see how that query could throw an outofmemory exception. What happens if you comment out the rest of the code from `conn.Dispose();` to the end of the method?

Comment: Pikoh - I tried that, nothing at all. It jumps straight from the DataTable `Fill` to the `catch`.

Comment: Mixxiphoid - I'm not dumping out the whole table to Excel. That's not even possible, Excel 2007 onwards only has 1 million rows. I'm running an expensive query that returns a very small result set.

Comment: Tim Schmelter - any thoughts? Could it be the use of the `SqlDataAdapter` rather than the `SqlDataReader`. I've read that the former loads the DataTable into memory. Even though the result set is small, I wonder if this is what is causing it to blow up?

Comment: Incidentally I tried `SqlDataReader` and no dice. Also fell over.

Comment: As I said in your other thread, wouldn't that all be easier, if you instead added the data to Excel via QueryTables.Add()?

Comment: Excel can read tons of data with PowerQuery and, especially, PowerPivot. That's because PowerPivot it uses columnstore compression. Excel DNA though just loads individual cells with no compression or columnar processing. Have you tried using *Excel's* purpose-built functionality?

Comment: To put it another way, you are *hobbling* Excel by using Excel-DNA to load the data. You can control PowerQuery/PowerPivot programmatically if you want

Comment: Furthermore, your code loads everything in memory with `sda.Fill` then converts all that data into another array. You are loading the same data multiple times before returning it. This doesn't scale in *any* application

Comment: Panagiotis, perhaps I'm being stupid but I'm not returning 'tons of data' to Excel. As the text clearly explains, the query results in only 160 rows (I tested it in Python). I have successfully run queries that result in over 1,000 rows in Excel without a problem. There is something very specific about the query that's causing the OOM. I'm certain this is to do with SQLite rather than Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not have anything which can cause OutOfMemoryException. So possibility is huge datatable and memory not getting recovered immediately. One possibility is - As you are reading excel.. it may have blank rows at the end, which may potentially can increase dt size.....

As datatable is managed object calling dispose will not really help.. But at lease you can clear dt everytime once it use is over..

Comment: No, Satish. As I said, the resulting query DataTable is very small. About 160 rows and 2 or 3 columns. I've successfully run queries that are far larger in terms of results returned with this code.