# Exporting SqlDataReader results to array in C#

Tags: c#, excel, sqlite, sqldatareader, excel-dna

I've written a function that that runs a SQL query, and have exposed it to Excel with ExcelDNA. The query itself uses a `SqlDataAdapter` and its corresponding `.Fill()` method to populate a `DataTable`.

I then iterate over the rows and columns of the `DataTable` to populate a 2D array that is defined as,

```
object[,] results = new object[dt.Rows.Count, dt.Columns.Count];
```

I can then directly return the `results` object to Excel, and everything is rendered correctly (strings as strings, and numbers as values).

However, I have run into a problem where certain SQL queries throw an "Out of Memory" exception when calling the `.Fill()` method.

I did a little bit of research and turns out that `SqlDataReader` might be more efficient as I'm interesting in only retrieving data into Excel and it will not load the result set into memory, but rather read them off row by row.

The problem I have is that there is no `.Fill()` method for `SqlDataReader`. I do have some working code where I can output the SQL results as a CSV file. Then I suppose I could write another function to import the CSV back into Excel. But this seems very circuitous.

Is there a more straightforward way to achieve this?

The full stack trace of the exception is included below.

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x80004005): out of memory
out of memory
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Reset(SQLiteStatement stmt)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Step(SQLiteStatement stmt)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
at UtilXL.Utils.UtilsSQLite.RunQueryCSLite(String SQLStatement, String FilePath, Boolean IncludeHeaders) in h:\Projects\UtilXL\UtilXL\Utils\UtilsSQLite.cs:line 37
```

Line 37 in referenced above is the `sda.Fill()` call.

This is the stack trace when running `SqlDataReader`,

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x80004005): out of memory out of memory
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Reset(SQLiteStatement stmt)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Step(SQLiteStatement stmt)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader()
at UtilXL.Utils.UtilsSQLite.RunQueryCSReader(String SQLStatement, String FilePath, Boolean IncludeHeaders) in h:\Projects\UtilXL\UtilXL\Utils\UtilsSQLite.cs:line 111
```

Comment: Wouldn't that all be easier, if you instead added the data to Excel via QueryTables.Add()? BTW this is tagged as SQL server although it is SQLite.

Comment: Thanks, corrected the tag. I don't understand why filling the DataTable itself is a problem if the result of the query is just a few rows. Aren't those the rows that are sent to the DataTable? Some queries that return many more rows (1000+) work just fine.

Comment: Somewhere (maybe in your other tread), you were saying 18 million rows and now a few! Probably "a few" is more realistic, a DataTable is very unlikely to be able to handle such load. I didn't see your code and doesn't have any idea about your data.

Comment: No. 18 million is the size of the full database. The query I'm running only returns 160 rows. So not sure why I get an OOM exception for such a small result set.

Comment: Then it is really odd. From error output, it isn't related to Excel. It breaks at loading to datatable. Have you tried with Linq instead (you can get IQToolkit via Nuget)?

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere. That's exactly why I was confused why everyone was harping on about Excel when I think the problem is at the SQLite end itself. I've not using IQToolkit, but let me take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with ExcelDNA, but ...

I think you should try to understand why you're getting an `OutOfMemoryException`.  It happens frequently in 32-bit applications that are using large object (in your case, probably strings).

It's true that using an `SqlDataReader` to process one row at a time will use less memory in the managed heap than loading all rows into a `DataTable`.  But you would then need to load one row at a time into Excel - e.g. from an array declared as:

```
object[,] results = new object[1, reader.FieldCount];
```

This will likely be slower than loading the two-dimensional array on one call.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. I don't understand why I get the memory exception. The result set itself is quite small, about 160 rows and 3 columns. Full details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41057622/c-sharp-outofmemory-exception-when-returning-a-small-datatable.

Comment: @insomniac - perhaps your code has a bug causing infinite recursion.  Do you have a stack trace for the OutOfMemoryException?  Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: just added the stack trace.

Comment: Incidentally I tried `SqlDataReader` and no dice. Also fell over.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer I think, but otherwise I don't know how to format the code. Grabbed your base code from your other tread, assuming you got IQToolkit from nuget, could you try something like this:

```
void Main()
{
  System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection con = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection( @"Data Source="+FilePath );
  SQLiteQueryProvider provider = new SQLiteQueryProvider(con, new ImplicitMapping(), QueryPolicy.Default);
    var data = provider.GetTable<MyTable>("MyTable")
    .Where(mt => mt.Level1 == "M_TO" && mt.AggCode == "C_DTA")
    .GroupBy(mt => new {mt.Date, mt.CompanyName})
    .Select(mt => new
     {
         Date = mt.Key.Date
         CompanyName = mt.Key.CompanyName,
         Sum = mt.Sum(t => t.Amount)
     }
    ).ToList();
```

// If it succeeds getting here then you are in good shape

```
  int numRows = data.Count() + (IncludeHeaders ?  1 : 0);
  object[,] ret = new object[numRows, 3];
  // ..
}

//// Entity Class
public class MyTable
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; } // varchar, really?
    public string AggCode { get; set; }
    public string Level1 { get; set; }
    //...
    public string Level5 { get; set; }
    // ...
    public string Level20 { get; set; }
}
```